# Changing individual colors of HTML text lines using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have been given an assignment to do some basic HTML stuff. That I have completed, but I want wo go a little *further*. We were given a christmas song and should show it in various ways, i.e. different colors for chorus and verse, a link to the Youtube video and so on. One verse looks like this:

```html
<p class ="verse">
    Some Line here<br/>
    and another one<br/>
    and another one<br/>
   you get the deal<br/><br/>
</p>
```

Verse is just a css class that defines the basic color.
I however have embedded the actual mp3, and with js am able to figure out the current position of the player, which I can then map to the timestamps of each line. So far no problem. I then want to use the now acquired postion in the song (like an integer i.e. 5 for "we're in line 5") to change the color of the current line. I have however no idea how to do that. I tried wrapping each line in a `<p class="lineN"></p>` with N beeing the line and then trying to change that (which did not work), but it also overwrote the color from `<p class="verse"></p>`.
I can program the "Where are we in the song" (From experience with Python, Kotlin and a little C#), but how do I change the colors?

```
Source from our teacher was just a text document and instructions on what to do. (https://pastebin.com/JJ99CFK8) and a list of requirements:
(https://pastebin.com/0txLgmzZ)

index https://pastebin.com/FhDWFaX4
alpha. https://pastebin.com/HEAXs7qW
script https://pastebin.com/01rwdrVK
style.css: https://pastebin.com/vz9xazh6

For your convenience: The whole thing on Mediafire: https://www.mediafire.com/file/jnqavlkb07rt06r/Christmassong.zip/file
```

I tried:

```html
<p class ="verse">
    <p class="line0">Lights on the tree under fallen snow</p>
    <p class="line1">You get a bit closer when winter&apos;s cold</p>
    <p class="line2">Now I can&apos;t wait &apos;til you&apos;re by my side<br/></p>
    <p class="line3">All of the best gifts, yeah, you just can&apos;t buy<br/><br/></p>
</p>
```

This also looks terrible, because the `<p>` inserts a linebreak (not a `<br>` but you get what I mean)

style.css

```css
.verse {
    color: #c70000;
} /* I want to keep these colors */

.chorus {
    color: #5500c4;
}
```

script.js:

```js
function getCurrentTime() {
    var player = document.getElementById("player");
    if (player != null) {
        return player.currentTime;
    }
}

function setLyricLine(linePosition) {
    return;
}

function returnNum(value) {
    if (value < startValue) {
        return;
    } // not done yet, but that's what I have in mind
    for (i in Range(timingIntervals.length)) {
        if (value < timingIntervals[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}


function main() {
    window.setInterval(main, 100) // call it continously
    document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = getCurrentTime(); // The time thing - so I can see it works
    document.getElementsByClassName("line0").style.color = "blue"; // that does nothing

}

window.onload = function() {
    main();
}
```

Comment: If it "did not work", then how did it over write the color for the verse?  That's an effect.  Please show us what you tried that did not work.

Comment: You need to show how you were changing the colour. Each element can have multiple classes, so `<span class="verse currentLine">` would have style for the combined rules of *verse* and *currentLine*. PS the *class* attribute can be used for lots of things, style is just a common use.

Comment: It just didn't budge changing colors with document.getElementsByClass("line0").style.color = blue;. Overwrote: The color of .verse is some red, with the lineN classes they all defaulted to black because I did not define 35 classes in style.css and (I think) the line classes superseded the verse class. I want to keep the original color of .verse, but change only the color of the current line.

Comment: I mean if you insist.
It was literally just the lyrics of the song.

Comment: I don't care about the song text I care about his format.

Comment: Its now all there good sir. With the complete mess my whole code is. Dont judge, I tidy up afterwards.

Comment: Uhm... She just told us to look the lyrics up on some website and then structure the html after that. Hence the .verse and .chorus classes you see.

Comment: Let me time to look at this...

Comment: I will, it's 1 Am here, ima going to bed.

Comment: [`getElementsByClass`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) returns a HTMLCollection. So `document.getElementsByClassName("line0").style.color = "blue";` should really be `document.getElementsByClassName("line0")[0].style.color = "blue";` (access the first and only element of the collection). Using IDs and [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) would be even better, since each ID is required to be unique.

Comment: In addition to @Minding comment, I would suggest changing the `lineX` classes into *id*'s. Since each line represents a unique segment of the document, it is easier to search and find that specific line.

In terms of structuring, I would keep the `<p class="verse">` paragraphs, but replace the `<p>` tags within it with `<spans>`'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a "solution".

It replaces the necessary spans to identify each row.

Example:

```html
<p class="verse">
    Without You I wish we were kissing under mistletoe<br/>
    The stars on the sky just can&apos;t match you glow<br/>
    Now I can&apos;t wait &apos;til you&apos;re by my side<br/>
    We&apos;ll be warm by the fire all night,<br/><br/>
</p>
```

become:

```html
<p class="verse">
<span data-line="0" data-uline="8">Without You I wish we were kissing under mistletoe</span>
<br>
<span data-line="1" data-uline="9">The stars on the sky just can't match you glow</span>
<br>
<span data-line="2" data-uline="10">Now I can't wait 'til you're by my side</span>
<br>
<span data-line="3" data-uline="11">We'll be warm by the fire all night,</span>
<br>
<br></p>
```

`data-line="2"` is relative paragraph line value
`data-uline="10"` is global line value

PS lines values start at zero

the `reformatSongTexts()` function do that and build the `AllLines` array

which looks like this:

```js
[ { ref: 0, p: "lyrics", linesCount: 1 } 
, { ref: 1, p: "verse",  linesCount: 4 } 
, { ref: 2, p: "chorus", linesCount: 3 } 
, { ref: 3, p: "verse",  linesCount: 4 } 
, { ref: 4, p: "verse",  linesCount: 4 } 
, { ref: 5, p: "chorus", linesCount: 6 } 
, { ref: 6, p: "bridge", linesCount: 6 } 
, { ref: 7, p: "chorus", linesCount: 7 } 
, { ref: 8, p: "outro",  linesCount: 1 } 
]
```

this make a total of 36 lines therefore.
for this page and codding:

```js
const songTexts = document.querySelectorAll('p.lyrics, p.verse, p.chorus, p.bridge, p.outro')

const AllLines = []

function reformatSongTexts()
  {
  let pCount = 0
    , lCount = 0
    ;
  songTexts.forEach(st=>
    {
    let count = 0
      , Lines = st.innerHTML.replace(/[\r\n]+/gm,'') // remove CR LF
                .split(/(<br\s*[\/]?>)/gi)           // cut lines
                .map(line=>line.trim())              // remove spaces
                .filter(line=>line.length)           // keep significatives

    st.innerHTML = ''

    Lines.forEach(line=>
      {
      if ( /<br\s*[\/]?>/.test(line)) 
        {
        st.innerHTML += `\n${line}`
        }
      else
        {
        st.innerHTML += `\n<span data-line="${count++}" data-uline="${lCount++}">${line}</span>`
        }
      })
    AllLines.push ( {ref: pCount++, p:st.className, linesCount:count })
    })
  }

reformatSongTexts()

// console.log( JSON.stringify(AllLines, 0, 2) )
 
document.querySelector('button#bt-test').onclick=_=>
  {
  let AllLines = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-line]')
    , lPos     = 0
    , lMax     = AllLines.length
    ;
  AllLines[lPos].classList.add('colorLine')
  let refIntv = setInterval(()=>
        {
        AllLines[lPos].classList.remove('colorLine')
        if (++lPos<lMax) AllLines[lPos].classList.add('colorLine')
        else clearInterval(refIntv)
        }, 800);
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family : Helvetica, Arial sans-serif;
  font-size   : 12px;
  }

.colorLine { background-color: pink; }
```

```html
<button id="bt-test">Demo line color</button>

<p class="lyrics">Lyrics:</p>
<p class="verse">
    Lights on the tree under fallen snow<br/>
    You get a bit closer when winter&apos;s cold<br/>
    Now I can&apos;t wait &apos;til you&apos;re by my side<br/>
    All of the best gifts, yeah, you just can&apos;t buy<br/><br/>
</p>

<p class="chorus">
    Wherever you go, you light up the room<br/>
    I hope that you&apos;ll make it back home soon<br/>
    Cuz, it won&apos;t feel like Christmas<br/><br/>
</p>

<p class="verse">
    Without You I wish we were kissing under mistletoe<br/>
    The stars on the sky just can&apos;t match you glow<br/>
    Now I can&apos;t wait &apos;til you&apos;re by my side<br/>
    We&apos;ll be warm by the fire all night,<br/><br/>
</p>

<p class="verse">
    ohh I wanna hold you while the bells are all ringing<br/>
    Want you to be here while the angel&apos;s singing<br/>
    Days are perfect when I got you near<br/>
    My only wish is you here<br/><br/>
</p>

<p class="chorus">
    Wherever you go, you light up the room<br/>
    I hope that you&apos;ll make it back home soo<br/>
    Cuz, it won&apos;t feel like Christmas Without You<br/><br/>
    Wherever you are, you brighten the<br/>
    Moon I hope that you&apos;ll make it back home soon<br/>
    Cuz, it won&apos;t feel like Christmas Without You (Without you)<br/><br/>
</p>

<p class="bridge">
    We could be outside dancing in the Moonlight<br/>
    Watching the sky roll over our heads<br/>
    We could be inside trying to sing the lines right<br/>
    Laughing until we fall out of bed<br/>
    So when I wake up on Christmas Day<br/>
    I hope the first thing I see is your face<br/><br/>
</p>

<p class="chorus">
    Wherever you go, you light up the room<br/>
    I hope that you&apos;ll make it back home soon<br/>
    Cuz, it won&apos;t feel like Christmas Without You<br/><br/>
    Wherever you are, you brighten the Moon<br/>
    I hope that you&apos;ll make it back home soon<br/>
    Cuz, it won&apos;t feel like Christmas Without You<br/>
    (it won&apos;t feel like Christmas Without You)<br/><br/>
</p>

<p class="outro">
    It won&apos;t feel like Christmas Without You...<br/>
</p>
```